# How is the Digital I/O Expander supposed to help me build the Color-Changing Vape Pen

Tags: shenzhen-io

As the *DX300 Digital I/O Expander* is unlocked right before the mission, I'm assuming that this is supposed to help build the circuit.

I can't figure out how to work around the limitation that the DX300 only ever outputs either 100 or 0, while the mission requires the input to vary between values like 100, 75, 50, 25 and 0.

What am I missing here? If I need to use additional MC4000s (or MC6000s) to control signal intensity after the DX300, why not just embed the DX300 functionality into those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now that the game actually shows the recommended parts, I figured I could answer this on my own. Unfortunately, the notifications are hidden, if you've already solved the puzzle. So I had to nuke my save and replay the game up to the Vape Pen, just to get a fresh look at it.
And the results are...

[image: DX300 - Part not recommended]
Well, I guess that answers that.

For people just tuning in, when the question was originaly asked, the game didn't work quite the same.
In the current build, you are given all the componets very early on in the game, but you are told, which part are recommended and which are not.
In the early days, you'd be drip fed parts as you progressed. It seems that DX300 was indeed unlocked at a time that caused some confusion as it was given to the players just before a task that *didn't make any use of it*. (You could optimize your earlier designs with it, tough.)

In short, DX300 not needed and most likely doesn't benefit you in any way, shape or form when desigining the Color-changing Vape Pen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't HAVE to use the expander. I managed to finish it just fine without it. In fact, I have gone on through a few more puzzles and didn't use the expander once.

Comment: Good to know, but I'm still baffled if the DX300 is supposed to help. And if so, how.